# Issue with Grammarbot api integrate with node js

Tags: node.js

I have use node.js as API for my application. in this I have use node package which is already giving by npm but it's giving me error for bad request. I have tried it using two ways provided by the npm.

```
const bot = new Grammarbot({
  API_key: "XXXXXX",
  language: "en-US",
  base_uri: "api.grammarbot.io",
});

bot.check("I can't remember how to go their", function (error, result) {
  if (!error) console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

the error like

```
 {
    "timestamp": "2019-10-10T10:20:38.301+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required String parameter 'text' is not present",
    "path": "/v2/check"
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error?? Also give some more inputs for easy debugging

Comment: Provide your error what you get back from your action. Add `console.log(error);` to the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some change in GrammarBot Nodejs library and upload in npm package. Please install below packages and run...

```
npm i custom-grammar-bot-api --save
```